# Copying files for deployment not working

Tags: .net, msbuild, web-deployment

In my csproj file I have the following:

```
<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      DeployTemplates;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      DeployTemplates;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
```

my DeployTemplate Target looks like this:

```
<Target Name="DeployTemplates">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="Views\Shared\Templates\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>Views\Shared\Templates\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

this works correctly to the extent that it does add these additional files to my PackageTmp folder under Views as expected.

when the actual deployment happen, these files are not deployed, any idea why that happen ?

Comment: If you are using visual studio, in solution explorer right click on the file and go to properties. Make sure the 'Copy to Output Directory' is NOT set to 'Do not copy'.

Comment: The files are NOT part of the project, I am using the above script to add them in runtime to the deployed package, which works, but beyind that, they are not on the deployed machine from somereason.

Comment: What I do for my application is that I have added those files to the solution (not any specific project) and manage the 'Copy to output directory' from solution explorer. You can either add them as 'Resources' or create a solution folder and just add the files to that folder.

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to override CollectFilesFromContent instead of CopyAllFiles...

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CollectFilesFromContentDependsOn>
       DeployTemplates;
       $(CollectFilesFromContentDependsOn);
    </CollectFilesFromContentDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution I end up finding

Comment: Just a heads up, for anybody trying to copy multiple folders/files: create multiple Targets (DeployTemplates2, DeployTemplates3, ...) and call them sequentially from the CollectFilesFromContentDependsOn, otherwise, all collected files end up in all DestinationRelativePaths...